# A way to call method once

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following, I want to move the setting of webDB and item outside of the following `public string method` which is an example how would I go about doing this.

```
public string Width
{
    get
    {
        if (webDB != null)
        {
            webDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
            Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = webDB.Items[StartItem];

            if (item != null)
            {
                Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field field = item.Parent.Fields["Identity_Page_Width"];

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Value))
                {
                    return field.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "964"; // returns default pixel width if Identity_Page_Width is not defined, or is null
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "964"; // If item is not found return default width.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "964";
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I have attempted to separate it:

```
public void GetConfiguration()
{
    if (webDB != null)
    {
        webDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");

        if (item != null)
        {
            item = webDB.Items[StartItem];
        }
    }
}
```

but I get stuck with trying to run the method within the code I get `method must have a return type`.

I then want to run this GetConfiguration only ONCE within the class somewhere so all methods don't need to contact the database and items data more then they have to.

I could do `MyClass class = New MyClass; Class.GetConfiguration();` but I don't want future coders to have to know this needs to be instantiated every time to continue. I would rather remove that dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `webDB` being instantiated is critical for most/all functionality of the class, consider initializing it in the instance constructor (if non-static), or a static constructor (if static)

Otherwise, I would create a

```
private InitializeWebDB(){if(webDB == null){...}}
```

which you can call within your class when needed.
Further, on properties which require access to this, I would use methods instead such as:

```
public String GetWidth(){InitializeDB(); ...}
```

which implies more logic/overhead than a simple property field return.

Comment: perfect in the constructor lol, sigh I should re-read basic programming book ide's for web development are making me forget the basics.!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be improved in a few ways. But to answer your question -
Why not use a static c'tor? This way you ensure it only runs once

```
public class SomeClass
{
    static SomeClass()
    {
        if (webDB != null)
        // etc. etc.
    }
    ... // other code
}
```

Comment: @Erix - that's true, thanks for that. I assumed this (incorrectly) based on the line `webDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");`
@Anicho - please let me know if you require webDB to be non-static.

Comment: `item = webDB.Items` this returns on [StartItem] `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property` I am struggling to make the StartItem static.

Comment: `private static Database webDB`        
`private static Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item;`

These are static but it seems I can't set StartItem to static

Comment: @Anicho, where is this StartItem defined? is it part of the same class?

Comment: Apologies it is defined within the same class making it static produced the wanted result is well.

Answer (score 1):

Making the `webDB` variable static would impose that it will only be null in your first Property call.

```
private static <whatevertype> webDB;
private static <whatevertype> item;

public void GetConfiguration()
{
    if (webDB == null)
    {
        webDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");

        if (item != null)
            item = webDB.Items[StartItem];
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue as in Jonno StartItem requries a reference.